# Вставка с форматированием

Tags: delphi, vba, ms-word

Нужно из delphi осуществить вставку с форматированием, записал макрос в vba в результате которого нужно перевести в delphi следующую строку

```
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
```

Но у меня не получилось этого сделать. Как можно по другому это сделать или же преобразовать этот код?

Comment: `MyWordApp.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat(...)`. Константа `wdFormatPlainText` = 22. Но это плохо - обращаться к ActiveXXX объектам в MSOffice.

Comment: Если референсная библиотека подключена, то вроде именно так и должно быть. Разве что потребуется явно указать объект, на котором находится требуемое выделение, типа **xlWorksheet1.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText**